# Booting elemetary OS with USB

Tags: boot

I am installing elementary OS on my computer as a primary operating system. Whenever I choose my USB as the boot device nothing happens. Can someone please walk me through doing this?

Comment: "nothing" means? what is your current OS? have you gave priority 1 to usb in BIOS ?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to boot into the usb device in order to install elementary, then the steps are located [here](https://elementary.io/es/docs/installation#download-elementary-os).  Now, if you have trouble booting to your usb device, I would reccomend:

1. Check in the BIOS of your computer if USB is selected as the **FIRST** boot device.
2. Reinstall the OS to the USB device with `UNetbootin` following the steps listed in the link.
3. Finally, give it another go.